# Get-AzDiagnosticSetting - Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-monitor

I am trying to get a diagnostic setting from within an Azure pipeline with the YAML :

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Ammend Diagnostic Settings 
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.environmentServiceConnection }}
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    ScriptType: ps
    inlineScript: |

        #$Diago = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId ""
```

If I executed the Get-DiagnosticSetting command with my normal 'admin' account I can see the diagnostic settings fine. I am using an SPN for the pipeline and I get the error:

```
Get-AzDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: 
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

So it is something to do with my permissions on my SPN - but I have no idea where the permission would be where I need to check (in Azure) to make sure I can get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Please assign `Contributor/Monitoring Contributor` from [`Azure Built-in Roles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#monitoring-contributor) to the SPN that is being used by the Azure Pipeline as a service connection to the Subscription.***

**I tested similarly by using a SPN in PowerShell with the below code :**

```
$ApplicationId=<ClientId>
$SecuredPassword= ConvertTo-SecureString <ClientSecret> -AsPlainText -Force
$TenantId="<tenantId>"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecuredPassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<Subscription>/resourceGroups/ansuman-resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/cloudshellansuman123"
```

output:

[image]

[image]